# PowerShell script for sending bulk emails

Tags: xml, powershell, email

I have written a script below that reads the email ID from the XML file. Loads the email ID filtered using group ID and then send emails to all the email IDs on that ArrayList. I don't know what is the problem below, I am not getting any emails.

```bsh
function Test {
   function Send-Mail {
        Param($smtp, $from, $to, $subject, $body)
        $smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtp)
        $mail = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
        $mail.From = $from
        $mail.To.Add($to)
        $mail.Subject = "subject goes here"
        $mail.Body = "This is test"
        $smtp.Send($mail)
    }
    #Read the xml file and typecast it to System.Xml.XmlDocument
    [Xml]$XmlData = Get-Content Email.xml
    $ArrayEmail = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    $subject = "Testing PowerShell email"
    $from = "a@134.com"
    $smtp = "test.test123.com"
    $body = "The body goes here"
    #get the email list from group id
    $ArrayEmail = $XmlData.emaillist.group |
                  Where-Object {$_.id -eq "IT"} |
                  Select-Object emailid
    $to = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    #store the email ids in array
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $ArrayEmail.emailid.Count; $i++) {
        $to.Add($ArrayEmail.emailid[$i])
    }
    Send-Mail -Smtp $smtp -From $from -To $to[$i] -Subject $subject -Body $body
 }
```

Here is my sample XML file:

```xml
<emaillist>
  <group id="IT">
    <emailid>a@123.com</emailid>
    <emailid>b@345.com</emailid>
  </group>
  <group id="Admin">
    <emailid>admin@admin.com</emailid>
  </group>
</emaillist>
```

Not sure what I have done wrong or missed anything as everything seems to be alright. But I still don't get any emails. My smtp is all good, the sender and receivers emails are all good as well.

Comment: Are there any errors when you run the script, or just no emails being received?

Comment: when i run the script in powershell ISE no errors. Just dont receive the emails.

Comment: Looks like the to email isn't being picked up, move the send-mail line inside the for loop above it and see if that works

Comment: Do you have any specific reason for using System.Net.Mail instead of the native Send-MailMessage Powershell cmdlet?

Comment: @ashim Do you call `Test` function that contains `Send-Mail` function? Remove `function Test{}` and just keep the code inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have there is called [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). After your `for` loop completes the value of the loop variable `$i` is the highest index of `$to` *plus one*. Hence `$to[$i]` evaluates to `$null`, because you're trying to access the element *after* the last element in the ArrayList (which doesn't exist), and PowerShell returns `$null` for things like that instead of throwing an error.

Replace this:

```
$ArrayEmail = $XmlData.emaillist.group |
              Where-Object {$_.id -eq "IT"} |
              Select-Object emailid
$to = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
#store the email ids in array
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $ArrayEmail.emailid.Count; $i++) {
    $to.Add($ArrayEmail.emailid[$i])
}
Send-Mail -Smtp $smtp -From $from -To $to[$i] -Subject $subject -Body $body
```

with this:

```
$to = $XmlData.emaillist.group |
      Where-Object {$_.id -eq "IT"} |
      Select-Object -Expand emailid
Send-Mail -Smtp $smtp -From $from -To $to -Subject $subject -Body $body
```

and the problem will disappear.

---

To have the mail sent to all recepients you need to add them one by one:

```
function Send-Mail {
    Param($smtp, $from, $to, $subject, $body)
    $smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtp)
    $mail = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
    $mail.From = $from
    $to | ForEach-Object { $mail.To.Add($_) }
    $mail.Subject = "subject goes here"
    $mail.Body = "This is test"
    $smtp.Send($mail)
}
```

However, rather than re-invent the wheel you should use the [`Send-MailMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-3.0) cmdlet, as others have already suggested:

```
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtp -From $from -To $to -Subject $subject -Body $body
```

Comment: I can receive the email with the changes but still doesnt solve the issue as i don't get email to all the the email ids in that group, just sends an email to the last email id from the list.